# How to remove a redirect on page reload?

Tags: angular

If go to any page, and then refresh the page, it will be redirected to the `/client` page.

How to make it so that when you reload the page, stay on the same page on which you were?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/client',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'client',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./profile/profile.module').then((m) => m.ProfileModule),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginModule),
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
})
export class RoutesRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Please check your code for following code-line:  `this.router.navigate(['client']);` As example in `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you specifically made redirect to /client route by the first element in the children array. Can you change it to below and observe the results?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'client',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
      }
    ]
  }
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: If I remove that, then there will always be a redirect to url `/`

Comment: No, there won't be. `/` represents the main layout component from which you can serve subsequent application routes e.g. `/contact`